# elasticsearch-head plugin will not open (not installed correctly?)

Tags: elasticsearch

The exercise:
proof of concept; currently 1000s of documents (word and pdf) on shared drives and users manually search and via windows searches
The idea is to have the documents stored and retrieved (the whole or part of MS word or pdf plus some metadata such as author, title, date created etc) via elastic search.

Up to now I have installed elastic search and git bash on my machine and created some documents such as the one below

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/irs_grants/grant/2?pretty' -d '
{
   "StudyTitle": "Identification of this and that",
    "ReferenceNumber": "09/125487",
    "PrincipalInvesigator": "Dr Smith",
 "ResearchTheme": "Cancer",
 "OrganisationType": "BRC",
 "OrganisationName": "Newcastle BRC"
}'
```

Running some queries... I know how to retrieve part or whole elastic search documents.

Next step was to install a webfront like elasticsearch head and start showing users the powers of basic elastic search install.

THE PROBLEM
after following (obviously I am missing something) installation instructions for elasticsearch-head plugin and then opening `localhost:9200` on my browser I get this:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Katie Power",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL for elastic search on local machine
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head

If head plugin is missing install it via this command from elasticsearch bin directory

```
bin/plugin.bat -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Comment: bin plugin directory is plugin.bat?when i click on this it opens and removes itself ...

Comment: I opened command prompt copied and pasted as advised above and hit enter to get error saying "...file directory does not exist...."

Comment: did you moved to current directory to elasticsearch's base directory, where u can see bin folder ?

Comment: where is the elastic search base directory? could you please specify the actual code i need to enter in the command prompt?